# programmatically get SharePoint Fast search content sources

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api, fastsearch

Need help to complete my C# program. I have four content sources in my farm. I need to get all the content sources and start full crawl if the content source is idle.

What is the best way to do it. Please can someone point me to a good article for Sharepoint search object model / fast search object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all [ContentSourceCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa637145%28v=office.12%29.aspx) using like this:

```
      /*
       Replace <SiteName> with the name of a site using the SSP
      */
        string strURL = "http://<SiteName>";
        SearchContext context;
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strURL))
        {
            context = SearchContext.GetContext(site);
        }
        Content sspContent = new Content(context);
        ContentSourceCollection sspContentSources = sspContent.ContentSources;

        foreach (ContentSource cs in sspContentSources)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NAME: " + cs.Name + "  ID: " + cs.Id);
        }
```

if you want to specific `ContentSource` than :

```
   string strContentSourceName = "FASTQuerySSA"; //which indicates the name of the content source to retrieve
   ContentSource cs = sspContentSources[strContentSourceName];
```

#### To check the crawl status values for a content source

```
 Console.WriteLine("Crawl Status = " + cs.CrawlStatus);
 Console.WriteLine("Crawl started at: " + cs.CrawlStarted.ToString());
 Console.WriteLine("Crawl completed at: " + cs.CrawlCompleted.ToString());
```

#### To start an incremental crawl of the content source

```
   cs.StartIncrementalCrawl();
   break;
```

#### To start a full crawl of the content source

```
   cs.StartFullCrawl();
   break;
```

#### To pause a crawl in process

```
  cs.PauseCrawl();
  break;
```

#### To stop a crawl of the content source

```
  cs.StopCrawl();
  break;
```

for more details see here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa679491%28v=office.12%29.aspx

### UPDATE:

Here's some code to enumerate all of the search service applications in your farm.  It DOES include all of them, including both FAST content and FAST query:

```
 SearchService s = new SearchService("OSearch14", SPFarm.Local);
 foreach (SearchServiceApplication ssa in s.SearchApplications)
   {
      //do something with the proxy here
   }
```

Comment: I tried this link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa679491%28v=office.12%29.aspx

but the issue with this that the object SearchContext has deprecated and we need to use the SarchServiceapplication object.

Content sspContent = new Content(SearchContext.GetContext(new SPSite(strURL)));

Comment: Hi,I have update my answer.pls have a look this.http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/02/20/getting-search-service-applications-and-proxies-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx